# how to give exception handling for json string if an array found instead of object usinc C#

Tags: c#, json, c#-3.0, choetl

I am having a json text file as :

```
[
    { 
        "productId":"17213812",
        "returnPolicies": {
            "user":"Regular Guest"
        }
    },
    {
        "productId":"17813832",
        "returnPolicies":[]
    }
]
```

and I am getting error for `returnPolicies` since it has different properties. But I want only `returnpoliciesuser` so If i use `e.returnpolicies.user` it is showing error for second array.. 
Anyone knows how to skip `"returnPolicies":[]` and search only `e.returnpolicies.user("returnPolicies":{"user":"Regular Guest"})` ?

Comment: The problem is not that they have different properties but that one is an object and the other an array.

Comment: Please add the code that reads the JSON. Do you use `ChoJSONReader`?

Comment: So how can I resolve it? any suggestions

Comment: yup im using ChoJSONReader

Comment: I don't know the `ChoJSONReader` but with other libraries you would need to change your json that both either use a list or an object.

Comment: @NtFreX Can you elaborate with code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do it.

```
using (var jr = new ChoJSONReader("sample6.json")
    .WithField("ProductId", jsonPath: "$.productId")
    .WithField("User", jsonPath: "$.returnPolicies.user")
    )
{
    foreach (var item in jr)
        Console.WriteLine(item.ProductId + " " + item.User);
}
```